# TCP client / server: server breaks when client program is stopped

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, raspberry-pi

I have a tcp server /client running on a Raspberry pi. The server reads the data from the USB port and sends it to port 8888 and ip "0.0.0.0". I first run the server using sudo ./server.py &, then I run the client using sudo ./client.py. Both scripts are located in the same directory on the Rpi. At first, everything seems to working fine; the data being printed using the client.py script corresponds to the data sent to the USB port. The problem arises when I stop client.py, for some reason, the server.py script also stops and it throws the error "Error Occured". I'm not sure why the server stops whenever the client stops. Is it a way to make the server to continue to run even if the client stops the connection?

```
 ##########################################
############ server.py ####################
##########################################
import socket
import serial

host = '0.0.0.0'        # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
port = 8888     # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port)

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0",9600,timeout = 1)

print(host , port)
s.listen(2)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
while True:
    try:
        readTest = ser.readline()
        #data = conn.recv(128)


        #if not data:
        #    break

        #print(readTest)
        conn.sendall(readTest)

    except socket.error:
        print("Error Occured.")
        break
ser.close()
conn.close()


#####################################################
################### client.py #########################
#####################################################
import socket

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 8888# The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((host, port)) 

while True:
        data = s.recv(128).decode('utf-8')  #2048
        print(data)
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure why the server stops whenever the client stops.

Because sendall will fail if the TCP connection breaks and this is causing the exception you see. And you explicitly break the loop if the exceptions happens:

```
while True:
    try:
        ...
        conn.sendall(readTest)         <<< this wail fail if the client disconnected

    except socket.error:
        print("Error Occured.")
        break                          <<< this will leave the while True loop
```

> Is it a way to make the server to continue to run even if the client stops the connection?

Given that you've explicitly break it is possible to not break out of the loop. Though it is unclear what should happen exactly. Given that the client is disconnected it will not receive the data.

Comment: Hi Steffen, I commented out the exception and replaced "conn.sendall" with "conn.send". Now when the client stops the connection I get the following error message:   File "./server.py", line 28, in <module>
    conn.send(readTest) 
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe    
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo python3 ./server3.py . I use ctrl + c to exit the client and when I do that I get the error message.

Comment: @Konan00781: it does not matter if you use `send` or `sendall` - if the client is no longer connected then sending will fail. You still have the explicit `break` and you still did not describe what exactly should happen when the client is no longer connected - because sending the data to the client can obviously not be done any longer.

Comment: Hi Steffen, I used to have an LTE modem that was sending data to a specific port and IP address and I had a python tcp client that would receive the data from the modem. The modem kept sending data no matter if the client was connected or not. I want to implement the same kind of communication using a Rpi. With the server / client tcp communication that I intend to design, the sender/server should keep sending to the specific port and ip address no matter if the client is connect or not. I'm not sure if it's something doable with tcp. thanks

Comment: @Konan00781: In TCP  you need to connection to send data because TCP is about having a __reliable__ transport between two peers. Therefore sending data without having a connected client makes no sense. In UDP you can send data to a specific ip+port instead and just hope that somebody will be there to read the data, i.e. __unreliable__ transport and no connection required.

Comment: I guess I should use UDP instead. This is kind of communication I'm looking for. 
Thanks